# Unable to access Samba server using Cloudflare Tunnel

Tags: linux, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers, tunneling, cloudflare-argo

I have a ubuntu server running locally with some services running along with samba server. I have already set-up cloudflare(s) tunnel using docker and can even access those using the tunnel. The problem arises when I try tunneling my samba service through it [I can access this service using local IP].

I tried verifying port which seems correct.
I have tried using CLI which due to reasons unknown messed up my homeassistant setup.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions only, and this doesn't sound like one. How about trying https://ServerFault.com

Answer (score -1):

I think it can be accessed over warp.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).